# Display label if list is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a div layer if list if empty into React page. I tried this:

```
        {(() => {
          if (!ordersList && ordersList.length === 0) {
            return (
              <div className="alert alert-warning">No Orders found</div>
            )
          }
        })()}
```

But it's not working. What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is incorrect. If list is empty, then !ordersList will be false.
So, the `<div>` won't be rendered.

You may try this:

```
{(() => {
          if (!ordersList || ordersList.length === 0) {
            return (
              <div className="alert alert-warning">No Orders found</div>
            )
          }
        })()}
```

Or even simpler:

```
{
  (!ordersList || ordersList.length === 0) && 
  <div className="alert alert-warning">No Orders found</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to conditionally render a div when `ordersList` (a variable/state that I presume is in your component) is empty. Then add this to your JSX returned by your component.

```js
{!ordersList.length && <div className="alert alert-warning">No Orders found</div>}
```